# using arrays for allowing flexibility

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

In a part of my program I am reading lines that contain `"ua, "` and setting them equal to however many lines I want to process. I want to use arrays to make this flexible to however many lines I want.

This is how it works with 4 lines

instead of having multiple else if statements, I want to simplify this so that I can define a number of lines I want to process and not have to edit this part

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath()))) {

    String line1 = null, line2 = null, line3 = null, line4 = null, line = null;
    boolean firstLineMet = false;
    boolean secondLineMet = false;
    boolean thirdLineMet = false;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("ua, ")) {

            if (!firstLineMet) {
                line1 = line;
                firstLineMet = true;
            } else if (!secondLineMet) {
                line2 = line;
                secondLineMet = true;
            } else if (!thirdLineMet) {
                line3 = line;
                thirdLineMet = true;
            } else {
                line4 = line;
                ProcessLines(uaCount, line1, line2, line3, line4);
                line1 = line2;
                line2 = line3;
                line3 = line4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted a solution?

Comment: Make it clear for us. What is your question?

Comment: instead of having multiple else if statements, I want to simplify this so that I can define a number of lines I want to process and not have to edit this part

Answer (score 1):

Alternative you can do following to achieve your goal.

```
int counter = 0;
int limit = 3; // set your limit
String[] lines = new String[limit];
boolean[] lineMet = new boolean[limit];

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains("ua, ")) {
        lines[counter] = line;
        lineMet[counter] = true; // doesn't make any sense, however
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter == limit){
    // tweak counter otherwise previous if will replace those lines with new ones
        counter = 0; 
        ProcessLines(uaCount, lines); // send whole array 
        lines[0] = lines[1]; // replace first line with second line
        lines[1] = lines[2]; // replace second line with third line
        lines[2] = lines[3]; // replace third line with fourth line

        // ProcessLines(uaCount, lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3]);
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: this is what I was trying to do. My goal is to be able to change one variable, lets call it `lineNumber` which will get me what I need

Comment: I think thats the way my answer is. Here I am using `limit` variable and sending whole array so that you dont have to depend on how many lines.

Comment: okay but after I process the lines how would I then set them equal to the next one?

Comment: Its in my original question, how i set `line1 = line2` and `line2 = line3`, etc

Comment: Well its easy `lines[0] = lines[1]..` but you have to tweak `counter` to satisfy your need, which I really dont know. If you can clarify that, then it will be easy for me to help. Also answer updated.

Comment: okay so once I get those first 4 lines with `"ua, "` then I start with the 2nd line and get the next 3.

Comment: You read 4 line containg `ua ` then you processed them and replace previous string with next one in array. So my guess is you only need to read one more line containing `ua ` and store that in lines[3] and do the processing again. Am I guessing correctly? If yes then make your `counter = 2` or come to chat to discuss. Link provided in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming reading the whole file in memory is ok, you could use the convenience methods provided by `Files`:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(yourFile, charset);
ProcessLines(uaCount, lines.get(0), lines.get(1), ...);
```

Or if you want to process the lines sequentially, but only up to a certain limit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit && i < lines.length(); i++) {
    processLine(lines.get(i));
}
```